# Simple Grammar Question about who noun clause

Tags: grammar, clauses

> Fill in the blanks
>
> I don't know ........
>
> 1. who is that man over there.
> 2. who that man over there is
> 3. who that man is over there.
> 4. that man over there who is

The first sentence that I thought about is "the man who is over there". which is not in the answers and I think it is right but anyway, we don't have this and we must choose from these four. I think the second ones seems familiar but I am not sure whether 2 or 3 is right.

Comment: #1 is typical of non-native speakers, but wouldn't often be used by the natives (it's essentially a *question* in its own right, without preceding *I don't know...*). #2 and #3 are both fine (though in practice #2 is probably much more likely in most contexts). And #4 is just seriously ungrammatical gibberish.

Comment: Noun clauses need context, like a full sentence. All those could be used in a conceivable universe when ***speaking*** but I am not going to write out a real sentence for you for each one.

Comment: Only 2. and 3. are OK, where "who that man over there is" / "who that man is over there" are subordinate interrogative clauses (embedded questions). Such clauses do not have subject-auxiliary inversion, so 1. is ungrammatical. The meaning is "I don't know the answer to the question 'Who is that man over there?'". And 3. is just gibberish, as FF says.

Comment: "Who is that man over there?"//" I told him who that man over there is but he didn't believe me."//"Who that man is over there is a matter of debate".//"That man over there who is eating a hot dog is not a nice man".// They all work.

Comment: The first one is the question form. And I did end up writing out examples. As you can see, this is not a simple question, in fact.

Comment: The OP made it clear that they were sentences (thus not elements or fragments of larger sentences). As written, they are all subordinate interrogatives, grammatical or otherwise.

Comment: @Lambie: Indeed. Because OP's ellipsis is what we use for a "pregnant pause" when transcribing speech, we're naturally inclined to parse it as, say, *"I don't know..." she trailed off. "Who is that man over there?"

Comment: If the OP's examples are complete sentences, which we have to assume since the OP says "the first sentence ...", then they are simple to parse.

Comment: The question is an independent sentence and it is just designed to assess grammar and not special cases in context. So with this in mind, both 2 and 3 are right?

Comment: @titansarus That's what I assumed. Yes, both 2 and 3 are right.

Comment: 4) is right also: **I don't know that man over there who is eating a hot dog.** after ***is*** there could be a multitude of things. It is fine.

Comment: No. it's not right. The OP has just made it 100% clear that they are all independent sentences, in which case 4 is ungrammatical. Wake up, Lambie!

Comment: @BillJ So please submit the answer so I can choose it as the best answer.

Comment: @titansarus OK, will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I don't know* ........

1. *who is that man over there.*
2. *who that man over there is.*
3. *who that man is over there.*
4. *that man over there who is.*

1 - 3 are subordinate interrogative clauses (embedded questions). Such clauses do not (normally) have subject-auxiliary inversion, so 1. is ungrammatical.

2 and 3 are fine, where the meaning can be glossed as "I don't know the answer to the question 'Who is that man over there?'"

4 is not an interrogative clause -- it's a noun phrase, but it is ungrammatical since "is" has no obvious complement.